# Trigger an event when an alarm sets off in the clock app

Tags: android

I would like to have some kind of a broadcast receiver or anything that would get triggered when an alarm starts ringing through the clock app so that I can send a request to my esp8266-based microcontroller that would turn the lights on. Would this even be possible?

Comment: Yes, what event does that microcontroller listen to do you know,

Comment: that microcontroller will just be listening for a trigger http request